# int to time_t* type for printing

Tags: c, printing, types, casting, time-t

Reading info from files and printing them out. I save the modification time from `stat` as an `int` called `mod_time` into a struct to recall later. However, when I want to use the `ctime()`function, I run into a problem because that takes a `time_t*` type variable. I tried using a typecast but that just resulted in a seg fault. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
void print(struct file_info **array)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; array[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
            printf("%s\n", array[i]->name);
            printf("mod_time: %s\n", ctime((time_t*)array[i]->mod_time));
    }
}
```

The above is the example with the typecast, which yielded a seg fault. The original one just excluded the `(time_t*)` typecast, which resulted in a "without a cast" warning.

Comment: I don't mind saving the time as `time_t`; what bothers me is having to save it as a pointer, because then I have to deal with a triple line of pointers and I'm already overwhelmed enough as it is with deleting the two iterations of pointers I presently have. If I saved it as a regular `time_t`, how would I turn it into a pointer to be used by `ctime()`?

Comment: I think you can simply use `&` operator to get a pointer from a variable. example: `&array[i]->mod_time`

Answer (score 2):

Since `ctime` function takes a pointer to `time_t`, I think a data of `time_t` must be on the memory, not only in an expression.

An example of making `time_t` data on the memory:

```
void print(struct file_info **array)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; array[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
            time_t tmp = (time_t)array[i]->mod_time; /* I'm not sure if this works */
            printf("%s\n", array[i]->name);
            printf("mod_time: %s\n", ctime(&tmp));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use of explicit casting in `ctime((time_t*)array[i]->mod_time)` is not right. You are taking an `int` and casting it to a pointer. It's not surprising that you get segmentation fault.

It will be better to use `time_t` for `mod_time` instead of an `int`.

If you don't have that option, you can use:

```
time_t t = array[i]->mod_time;
printf("mod_time: %s\n", ctime(&t));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming POSIX/C99 or more you could use a compound:

```
printf("mod_time: %s\n", ctime(&((time_t){array[i]->mod_time})));
```